# passing form data to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two HTML pages: form.html and display.html. In form.html, there is a form:

```
<form action="display.html">
    <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The form data is sent to display.html. I want to display and use the form data `serialNumber` in display.html, as shown below:

```
<body>
    <div id="write">
        <p>The serial number is: </p>
    </div>
    <script>
    function show() {
        document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = serialNumber;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

So how can I pass the `serialNumber` variable from form.html to display.html so that the above code in display.html will show the serial number and the JavaScript function show() gets the `serialNumber` from the first HTML?

Comment: you need to use a server side language. for example, PHP

Comment: @Eric: I can't run PHP since I'm writing mobile web apps. So I can only use HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: @tonga Why can't you use a server-side technology?  "because you're writing mobile web apps" isn't really an answer.  Any app that can be viewed on a mobile browser is still just a web app, hosted by a server.  Do you have hosting restrictions that don't permit the use of dynamic page languages?

Comment: @Peter: My mobile app is a local app. So it does not connect to any web server. That's why I can't use a server-side technology.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful to know. You might consider stating this in the question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you have no option to use server-side programming, such as PHP, you could use the query string, or GET parameters.

In the form, add a `method="GET"` attribute:

```
<form action="display.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When they submit this form, the user will be directed to an address which includes the `serialNumber` value as a parameter. Something like:

```
http://www.example.com/display.html?serialNumber=XYZ
```

You should then be able to parse the query string - which will contain the `serialNumber` parameter value - from JavaScript, using the `window.location.search` value:

```
// from display.html
document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = window.location.search; // you will have to parse
                                                                     // the query string to extract the
                                                                     // parameter you need
```

See also [JavaScript query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string).

---

The alternative is to store the values in cookies when the form is submit and read them out of the cookies again once the `display.html` page loads.

See also [How to use JavaScript to fill a form on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183572/how-to-use-javascript-to-fill-a-form-on-another-page/12183659#12183659).

Comment: @tonga See [How can I get query string values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) for examples and methods of processing the query-string.

Comment: @tonga Edited a couple of minutes ago. Try reloading.

Comment: @Richard: Thanks for pointing to the query string. Since I'm doing mobile web apps, all HTML files are stored locally on the phone. So does query string work as if it works on regular websites?

Comment: @tonga - I'm not sure they will, but you should just try and see if it works. If it doesn't use cookies and check out the second question I linked to. Cookies should work, but they can be messier since they have a longer lifespan than query string parameters.

Comment: @Richard: Thanks. I will give a try to see if it works on phone locally as well.

Comment: @Richard: I just used the query string in the second html file display.html but it doesn't work properly. It works on my desktop browser and shows the serial number I entered in the first page. But when I tried on my Android phone, it shows blank page without any serial number info. I guess maybe it's related to the different behavior of Android browser as compared to desktop browser like Firefox?

Comment: @Richard: I just retried it and finally it works on my phone. I think something was messed up so I didn't see the parsed query string initially. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it works. When I entered "ABC" in the first page and clicked "Submit" button, it went to the second page and the popup message box shows "ABC" after the query string gets parsed.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen My form contains 6 fields and when using the GET method to send the data, only the last input value is present in the URL

Comment: Is this a security risk if used for sensitive content like passwords?

Comment: In the URL as a query string parameter? Yes.

Answer (score 10):

You need the get the values from the query string (since you dont have a method set, your using GET by default)

use the following tutorial.

http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: that code is causing a browser error for me! *Your file was not found*

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use "localStorage". You can easealy request the value with javascript in another page.

On the first page, you use the following snippet of javascript code to set the localStorage:

```
<script>    
   localStorage.setItem("serialNumber", "abc123def456");
</script>
```

On the second page, you can retrieve the value with the following javascript code snippet:

```
<script>    
   console.log(localStorage.getItem("serialNumber"));
</script>
```

On Google Chrome You can vizualize the values pressing F12 > Application > Local Storage.

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 4):

```html
<form action="display.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In display.html you should add the following code.

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var sn = getParameterByName('serialNumber');

document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = sn;

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using pure JavaScript.It's very easy using local storage.
The first page form:

```js
function getData()
{
    //gettting the values
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password= document.getElementById("password").value; 
    var telephone= document.getElementById("telephone").value; 
    var mobile= document.getElementById("mobile").value; 
    //saving the values in local storage
    localStorage.setItem("txtValue", email);
    localStorage.setItem("txtValue1", password);
    localStorage.setItem("txtValue2", mobile);
    localStorage.setItem("txtValue3", telephone);   
}
```

```css
  input{
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  label{
    color: rgb(16, 8, 46);
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  #data{

  }
```

```html
   <fieldset style="width: fit-content; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 30px;">
        <form action="action.html">
        <legend>Sign Up Form</legend>
        <label>Email:<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></label><br />
        <label>Password<br />
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/></label><br>
        <label>Mobile:<br />
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"/></label><br />
        <label>Telephone:<br />
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"/></label><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getData()">
    </form>
    </fieldset>
```

This is the second page:

```js
//displaying the value from local storage to another page by their respective Ids
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("txtValue");
document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("txtValue1");
document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("txtValue2");
document.getElementById("data3").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("txtValue3");
```

```html
 <div style=" font-size: 30px;  color: rgb(32, 7, 63); text-align: center;">
    <div style="font-size: 40px; color: red; margin: 0 auto;">
        Here's Your data
    </div>
    The Email is equal to: <span id="data"> Email</span><br> 
    The Password is equal to <span id="data1"> Password</span><br>
    The Mobile is equal to <span id="data2"> Mobile</span><br>
    The Telephone is equal to <span id="data3"> Telephone</span><br>
    </div>
```

## Important Note:

Please don't forget to give name "action.html" to the second html file to work the code properly. I can't use multiple pages in a snippet, that's why its not working here try in the browser in your editor where it will surely work.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Get" Method to send the value of a particular field through the browser:

```
<form action="display.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is as described;
You have to send action to a different servelet from a single form and you have two submit buttons and you want to send each submit button to different pages,then your easiest answer is here.

For sending data to two servelets make one button as a submit and the other as button.On first button send action in your form tag as normal, but on the other button call a JavaScript function here you have to submit a form with same field but to different servelets then write another form tag after first close.declare same textboxes there but with hidden attribute.now when you insert data in first form then insert it in another hidden form with some javascript code.Write one function for the second button which submits the second form. Then when you click submit button it will perform the action in first form, if you click on button it will call function to submit second form with its action. Now your second form will be called to second servlet.

Here you can call two serveltes from the same html or jsp page with some mixed code of javascript

An **EXAMPLE** of second hidden form

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="IPDBILLING" id="MyForm" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="admno" id="ipdId" value="">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Print() {
        document.getElementById("MyForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*first html page*

<form action="display.jsp" >
    <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


*Second html page*
<body>
<p>The serial number is:<%=request.getParameter("serialNumber") %></p>
</body>


you will get the value of the textbox on another page.
```

Comment: This answer is for java supported servers. But the question is only html.