# how to pass id to another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Below is my javascript in `nextPage.js`. When I click on it, it must pass `category_id` to the `reportlist.html` page. Please help me.

```
var base_url = "http://dev.edfutura.com/nithin/jps/edfuturaMob/";  

$(document).on("pageinit", "#catlist", function() {
    var submitUrl = base_url+"categorylist/get_categorylist"; 
    $.ajax({
        url: submitUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            var categoryList = $('#category');
            var category;
            for(var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++) {
                category = response[i];
                var a = $('<a>').attr('href', 'reportlist.html').html(category.category_name);
                categoryList.append($('<li>').attr('id', category.category_id).append(a));
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

My first page is `nextPage.html` and my `category_names` are stored in a list as links through JS.

```
<body id="category_id">
    <div data-role="page" id="catlist"> 
        <div  id="loading"></div>  
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h1>category</h1>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <form id="nextForm" > 
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="category">      
                    <li id="catid"></li>  
                </ul> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>                 
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing form data to another HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some data when you change the page, you must use [request parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

When you want to pass data in `href` link, you should use `GET` request like this:

```
reportlist.html?category_id=12
```

Then you can read your data similarly to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/4772988