# Permanent style css change with cookies light and dark theme with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, local-storage

Hi id like that the color of the theme remains permanet when user go to another page, or when users left the web site and then return. I think that the way is with cookies, but i dont know how to do, thanks.

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}

<p class="copyright theme">
    <a onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/dark.css')" href="#">Dark theme</a> 
    <a onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/style.css')" href="#">Light theme</a>
</p>
```

How i can implement with local storage?

Comment: You could use `localStorage` instead, if you are targeting modern browsers.

Comment: hi, how i can implement with localstorage?

Comment: Hey, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34530670/462627