# Phoenix - Site-wide Search Functionality Using DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working on a Phoenix web app and am trying to figure out a way to implement a global search box that is located in the nav bar that will point to and perform a search on a table located at `/users` that is built with DataTables. As I have it now, when I submit a search via the search bar, it redirects to `/users` but does not apply the search to the table.

app.html.eex (layout):

```
<form id="custom-search-input" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" action="/users">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="ee-search" type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Search" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

app.js:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#employeeTable').DataTable();
} );

var table = $('#employeeTable').DataTable( {
  "lengthMenu": [ [15, 50, 75, 150, -1], [15, 50, 75, 150, "All"] ]
} );
```

I found this in the DataTables API which I have placed in app.js:

```
$('#ee-search').on( 'keyup', function () {
  table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

I apologize ahead of time...my javascript skills are practically non-existent. How do I get the search input to apply to the DataTable? I assume there is a way to link the form submission/javascript code/DataTable? If you need more info or code, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to reference your `table` variable the way you're trying to if you define it where your `keyup` handler can see it.  You might want to put a breakpoint on your table.search line and evaluate table to see if it's undefined.  Learning javascript, in my experience, is partly a matter of looking up syntax and partly a matter of walking around in the DOM objects to see what's really there.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question clearly last post.  Is the search box that the user types in on a different page from the table that displays the filtered results?

Comment: @BobRodes yes the search box is on a static nav bar that can be accessed from anywhere. The `/users` page is basically an employee directory and I'm trying to make it accessible from anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to pass data from one page to another without making a round trip to a server: GET data, cookies, and session variables in local storage.  Of these, I'd start by using GET data.

So, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page), which (is one example of many, and) explains how to pass data from one page to another using the GET mechanism.  Basically, you have to add `method="GET"` to your form's attributes, and then parse the resulting querystring from your `\users` page.

Then, to perform the search, just call the `search()` method, passing your parsed string as an argument, and call the `draw()` method, so:

```
myTable.search( myTextString ).draw();
```

The DataTable will apply the search term, filter the results, and redraw the table.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've got it to the point now where it parses the GET params and enters it as the value of the search box on the `/users` page, however, it doesn't submit the search. Is there some additional code I need to add to the jQuery that will actually submit the search? I tried to add .submit() but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to use the `filter()` method to apply the search criteria.  Sorry, I missed that, naively thought that just plugging the text in would apply the filter.  Edited my post.

Comment: I see where you were going with `filter()`, however, the `search()` method provided the results I was looking for. I updated your answer to reflect this. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Outstanding. I didn't quite like filter, since it applied to specific columns.  `search` is exactly the thing to use.  Good find!  I've further updated the answer to remove the the stuff about programmatic updating of the search box, since the `search` method handles it.  In the end, it's quite simple.