# Javascript Navigate between pages with data

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 pages and I am trying to navigate from page 2 to page 1. Is there any option to bind object from page 2 to page 1 element with plain javascript?

The below is the basic algorithm I am trying. I am trying to check if that is possible or not and implement based on some pointers.

**Page 1 code**

```
<div id="page1Element">
</div>
```

**Page 2 code**
Go Back

```
<script>
    goBack();
    function goBack() {
        var obj = {some object values};
        document.getElementById("page1Element").innerHTML = obj.value;
        window.history.back();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing form data to another HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page)

Answer (score 1):

If these are totally different pages and both are loaded by hitting the server then you have the following options:

1. Send all the data to the server and have the new page render using that data.
2. Save the data in [localStorage](http://devdocs.io/dom/window/localstorage) and have the new page read that data out of localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in your browser localstorage and access it in page 2.