# how to pass js value from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fetching names(name 1, name2, name3) from api using get method

for eg: on clicking name1, using anchor, I want to display the same name on page2.html

```js
<a href='page2.html' onclick='getvalue(this)'>+data.items.name+</a>

function getvalue(click){
    var clicked=click.innerHTML;
    document.getElementbyId("name").innerHTML=clicked;
}
```

**page 2.html**

```
<p id="name"></p>
```

But I am getting undefined value, How to achieve the solution?

Comment: use localstorage.

Comment: can u tell me hoe it is implemented, new to js

Comment: you are redirecting to page2 while click on getvalue?

Comment: yes and want to fetch the same value on page 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing form data to another HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

On page1:

```
function getvalue(click){

    var clicked=click.innerHTML;
    //document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=clicked;
    localStorage.setItem("clicked",clicked);
}
```

On page2:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var clickedval =  localStorage.getItem("clicked");

});
```

Comment: I am getting null in alert

Comment: thanks , it worked, But i want to display in <h1> tag

Comment: answer updated. Please check. just append value to h2

Comment: its giving undefined noe

Comment: It worked using var a=localStorage.getItem("clicked");

   document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=a;

Answer (score -1):

set value in session

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');//to set value
```

get value

```
sessionStorage.getItem('key');//to get the value
```

Comment: This answer is not related to the question which OP is asking.