# is there a way to get the value of the attribute of a anchor tag in HTML after it is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have  tags in HTML with different data in the attribute and i want to get the data from one of the attribute of the  tag after redirecting of the page to href link without using post and get data

```
<a class="tile checklogin" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" refcon="hotels/bkhtl/1" data-target="#login">
<a class="tile checklogin" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" refcon="hotels/bkhtl/2" data-target="#login">
<a class="tile checklogin" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" refcon="hotels/bkhtl/3" data-target="#login">
```

i want to get the result of the refcon of  tag after reaching to the another page not in the current page but to the other page where the hyper link takes to

Comment: Well, after a new pageload, the old dom-elements are gone... So you have to think of a way to keep the desired information...

Comment: I would suggest using [a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page) to do what you're looking for

Comment: i think u should use [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_localstorage)