# Showing html form data on subsequent pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Page 1, complete a HTML form.  Submitting form links to page 2.
Page 2+, shows a story populated by the answers to the HTML form.

I can't find a why to bring back elements of the HTML form to complete gaps in future pages.  Should I be looking at trying to use Javascript or to learn some PHP to store and then re-use the form data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing form data to another HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page)

Comment: Well.. you've answered yourself :-) Yes, you can learn JavaScript to achieve desiring result or learn some PHP to save the data from form on page 1 and use them on pages 2+

Comment: If you don't want to write server-side code you should go for the [html web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will some sort of server side programming, store data locally and then retrieve it with javascript or passing the information to the page using [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Maybe other options are possible but those are the things that come to mind right now. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693871/2484416) for an example of the last method I mentioned.