# How to get localStorage in Javascript working in Firefox 71.0

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Below are two files. One to do a  localStorage  and two to retrieve the variable first_name. I get a null result when I try to retrieve the variable first_name value of "Peter". I have tried windows.localStorage to no avail. The URL called by the first file opens but no retrieval.

File 1

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem("first_name", "Peter");
    window.open(URL);
</script>
```

File 2 - URL

```
<script>
    first_name="";
    localStorage.getItem("first_name");
    console.log("fn",first_name); 
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to use the return value of the call to `getItem`

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Could you please elaborate. Much obliged for the comment.

Comment: Functions often return values. In order to use the values those functions return, you have to assign the return values to variables (or use them immediately).

Answer (score 2):

You don't set `localStorage.getItem("first_name");` to a variable. Instead, your code should look like this:

```
var first_name = localStorage.getItem("first_name");
console.log("fn",first_name);
```

Comment: Thanks Rojo, but still get a null result.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, those are the right calls to localStorage (aside from not actually storing the output of getItem, as another answer has pointed out).

However, if "URL" is in a different domain or subdomain than the page where the first script runs, they won't share the same localStorage! Reference this question: [In HTML5, is the localStorage object isolated per page/domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain)

If this is in fact the case, you have a somewhat complicated problem on your hands. Depending on your needs and framework, you might find some useful ideas in one of these questions:

- [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)
- [passing form data to another HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693758/passing-form-data-to-another-html-page)

Comment: Thanks ben, but both files are in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("first_name", "Peter");
var first_name = window.localStorage.getItem("first_name");
console.log(first_name);
```

Comment: No other code being used apart from the javascript code in the  header section. And as far as I know there is no restriction on writing to my domain as I write files to it all the time like the two small files E1 and E2. I fancy I could use local storage some years ago in a different program and perhaps on a different computer.

Comment: You ever figure out what the deal was with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that windows.localStorage.setitem is storing the value "Peter" in the variable first_name. However the second file when called gives a null result for first_name.

2nd file is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>

   <script>
        if(!localStorage.getItem('first_name')) 
            {
                 prompt(" first_name there");
            }
        else
            {
                 prompt("first_name not there");
            }
        var second_name = localStorage.getItem("first_name");
        console.log("fn",second_name); 
    </script>
</html>
```