# Get HTML input value to a a P tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and JS and I am trying to get a value from an input in a page called second.html and send it to a p tag in a page called third.html.

Not sure whether this is something possible but on second.html I have some input-elements in which once some information is written I want to press a button and then that would take me to another page (third.html), in which the value that I got from the input in the second.html would be used in a p tag. I have been able to get the input value and move to the third.html page, however, assigning the value to the p-element is where I am failing. This is the code:

second.html

```
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Second page</h1>
    <label for="ticket">ticket:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="ticket2"
      name="ticket"
      required
      minlength="4"
      maxlength="8"
      size="10"
    />
    <button onclick="ticket()">Click me</button>
  </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ticket() {
  let ticketp3 = document.querySelector("#specials p").innerHTML;
  let valueticket = document.getElementById("ticket2").value;
  ticketp3 = valueticket;
  parent.location = "third.html";
}
```

third.html

```
<div id="specials">
      <h1>thrid page</h1>
      <p></p> 
    </div>
```

Comment: see query parameters, i.e. `my-new-page.html?key=value`

Comment: See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693871/1533592)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a information to another tab can be really a problem because you call the id #specials before it even exists, the id does not exists yet, you have to call the page first. And i think you can't call another page and try to do it, i suggest you using local storage to store the information and use it before! Just use the following:

```
localStorage.setItem("inputvalue", put here the input value)
```

And to get the value on the other page use getItem :)

Edit: sorry for the bad english, i'm from Brazil

Answer (score 0):

You could use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this:

ticket():

```
...
localStorage.setItem('ticket', valueticket);
...
```

third.js:

```
window.onload = () => {
  const valueticket = localStorage.getItem('ticket')
}
```