# JS Query String - take particular word out of page url

Tags: javascript, forms, query-string

After submitting a form, I get redirected to another form where I want to populate email field with the value from previous form. I have next url:

```
mysite.com/a/blog/?email=test%40email.com#form_20
```

How to make input with id="email" populated with **test@email.com** using javascript ?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @MA-Maddin for helpful link: [How to use JavaScript to fill a form on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183572/how-to-use-javascript-to-fill-a-form-on-another-page/12183659#12183659)
With this, I get email like: **test%40email.com** . I am wondering, how to combine

```
decodeURIComponent('%40')
```

with provided solution:

```
window.location.search.replace(/^\?email=/, '')
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183572/how-to-use-javascript-to-fill-a-form-on-another-page/12183659#12183659

Comment: Thanks @MA-Maddin, do you know how to combine that with decodeURIComponent('%40'), so I can have normal email :)

Comment: `var GET = {};
var queryString = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
queryString.forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
    var splitPair = keyValuePair.split('=');
    var paramName = splitPair[0];
    var paramVal = decodeURIComponent(splitPair[1]);
    GET[paramName] = paramVal;
});

console.log(GET['email']);`

Comment: var uglymail = window.location.search.replace(/^\?email=/, ''); var mail = decodeURIComponent(uglymail); this is what I used. It is ok now. Thanks for help.