# how to read form data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is the form data.

```
<div>
    <form name="payform" action="pay.html" method="POST">
        <div>
            <input id="customerName" name="firstname" ng-model="customerName" style="display:none"/>
            <input style="display:none" id="txnid" name="txnid" ng-model="transactionid" />
            <input type="submit" name="paybutton" id="payit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When i submit data the contents are posted to **pay.html**. How can I read those data using javascript on **pay.html** page?

Answer (score 1):

The **action** attribute specifies where to send the `form-data` when a **form** is `submitted` and usually it's a `server side` method.

But,

If you don't use `server-side` programming, such as `PHP` or `C#`, or `Java`, you could use the `query` string, in order to `GET` search parameters.

For this, you have to use `window.location.search` property in order to get the search params.

```js
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=4";
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.search;
console.log(c);
```

> get is not secure right? i cannot use method get. only allowed method
>   is post.

POST data is data that is handled server side. And `Javascript` is `client side` technology. The idea is that there is no way you can read a post `data` using **JavaScript**.

You can use `localStorage` in order to access data from `anywhere`.

Comment: can u tell more specifically?

Comment: get is not secure right? i cannot use method get. only allowed method is post.

Comment: @ajithes111, have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are sending data of the `FORM` through `POST`. If you are sending data through `POST` method, then you need a 'Server' which processes the data received from the HTML page and then forward the same data as response to the requested `HTML Page`.

If you change the Form data to `GET`, then you can read the data by using JavaScript.
If you still want to use `POST`, you can use Cookies to store and retrieve data on another page. [Here are the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183572/how-to-use-javascript-to-fill-a-form-on-another-page/12183659#12183659)!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can send form data in URL, just set the form submission's method as "GET".

Then the url will be "`localhost:XXXX/pay.html?firstname='himanshu'&txnid='1'`".

Now at pay.html, you can read this URL from javascript methods and parse this url to get all the parameters.
Use `window.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [location.search](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp)

```
var params = {};

if (location.search) {
    var temp = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        var dt = temp[i].split('=');
        if (!dt[0]) continue;
        params[dt[0]] = dt[1] || true;
    }
}

console.log(params.abc);
console.log(params.xyz);
```

Comment: post is the preferred method.

Comment: ah yes, then he need to change to GET on the method, due he is not using any server side programming.